# Confirm email before registration - Wordpress

Tags: user-registration, email-verification

Dear Wordpress Experts,

I have been looking for a solution to tackle an easy sing up problem. I am impressed with Wrike.com sign up system, where they ask you only email ID at the first stage.

Here is how I am expecting wordpress sign up process to work:

1. Just input the email and click signup
2. Confirmation email is sent to user to confirm email
3. Once they click the confirm link, they will be taken to a Thank you page with additional details to fill
4. At this step, I want to finish collecting rest of the details.

I have installed and tested all popular registration plugins and tried all the QA listed here. But no one talks about this method of registration (email alone)

Is this possible with Wordpress or do you think any unpopular plugin can do the job?

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Yes this is possible in WordPress. I have done this as custom functions. Unfortunately I don't know what plugin that can do the job.